# Can't add multiple annotations on a groovy method?

Tags: groovy, annotations, testng

```
 when I add two annotations to a method like this       

@Parameters({"userName",""})
@Test
public void replyMaster()
{

}
```

got this error

```
 Multiple markers at this line
- Groovy:unexpected token: @ @ line 40, column 2.
- Duplicate field ReplyTest.@
- Groovy:The field '@' is declared multiple times.
```

my configuration:jdk 1.7,testng 6.8,groovy 2.0(installed with groovy eclipse plugin)

why?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If this is a Groovy file, then

```
@Parameters({"userName",""})
```

Should probably be:

```
@Parameters(["userName",""])
```

Or

```
@Parameters(["userName",""] as Object[])
```

Not sure, I haven't used TestNG.  But you can definitely have multiple annotations per node with Groovy, it's just this isn't how groovy does lists or arrays